# PHP header and session tags not working after “json_encode” is called

Tags: php, ajax, session, authentication

I am passing the login form details from HTML to PHP using Ajax. The details get passed properly and all functions work and alert also works based on the output.

But, If I add the following session statements below `json_encode`, it does not work. The output is proper in the “Network Tab” of Chrome after doing “Inspect Element,” but the header function does not work and the alert also does not come which is specified in Ajax on success or faliure.

Here is the code:

```
<?php
  ob_start();
  session_start();
  $servername = "localhost";
  $username = "root";
  $password = "";
  $dbname = "kites";

  //Create Connection
  $conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

  //Check connection
  if(!$conn)
  {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
    alert("Connection failed");
  }
  else
  {
    if( empty($_POST['loginusername']) && empty($_POST['loginpassword']) )
    {
      echo json_encode(array('status'=>false,'msg'=>'No arguments provided'));
    } 
    else
    {

  $loginusername = $_POST['loginusername'];
  $loginpassword = $_POST['loginpassword'];

  $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM register_form WHERE username = ?");
  $stmt->bind_param("s", $loginusername);

  if($stmt->execute())
  {
    $result = $stmt->get_result();
    $num_of_rows = $result->num_rows;
    if($num_of_rows > 0)
    {
      $user = $result->fetch_assoc();
      $salt = $user['salt'];
      $encrypted_password = $user['password'];
      function checkhashSSHA($salt,$password)
      {
        $hash = base64_encode(sha1($password . $salt, true) . $salt);
        return $hash;
      }
      $hash = checkhashSSHA($salt,$loginpassword);
      if($encrypted_password == $hash)
      {
        echo json_encode(array('status'=>true, 'msg'=>'Login Successfull'));
        session_regenerate_id();
        $_SESSION['username']=$loginusername;
        session_write_close();
        //here you can redirect on your file which you want to show after login just change filename ,give it to your filename.
        header("Location:http://localhost/kites/profile.php");
      }
      else
      {
        echo json_encode(array('status'=>false,'msg'=>$encrypted_password ));
      }
    }
    else
    {
      echo json_encode(array('status'=>false,'msg'=>'Wrong username. Please check it and try again'));
    }
  }
  else
  {
    echo json_encode(array('status'=>false,'msg'=>'Something went wrong. Please try again!'));
  }
} } ?>
```

If I remove the following statements:

```
session_regenerate_id();
$_SESSION['username']=$loginusername;
session_write_close();
header("Location:http://localhost/kites/profile.php");
```

The code works properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code block for which you are getting error :
You change that to

```
session_regenerate_id();
$_SESSION['username']=$loginusername;
session_write_close();
echo json_encode(array('status'=>true, 'msg'=>'Login Successfull'));
```

And in your Ajax success function you can do:

```
if(status){
   //redirect using window.location
   window.location = "your_redirect_url";
}
```

P

Answer (score 1):

You can't send headers in PHP after sending any output. Use output buffering - for workaround

```
ob_start(); // you have already start buffering. that's correct
...
echo json_encode(array('status'=>true, 'msg'=>'Login Successfull'));
session_regenerate_id();
$_SESSION['username']=$loginusername;
session_write_close();
//here you can redirect on your file which you want to show after login just change filename ,give it to your filename.
header("Location:http://localhost/kites/profile.php");
ob_end_flush();
...
```

But after all, you should not use redirection by `header` within ajax calls. It won't work as expected.

Comment: PHP automatically flushes the buffer at the end of script execution, so `ob_end_flush();` doesn't add anything. This is not a solution.

Comment: @Tristan, really? how can you force any ouput before sending header?

Comment: @JakeGould , Right. I've add some caution to my post